# How can I call JavaFXApplication from Java Swing/GUI? Is this even possible?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I used jframe in most of my GUIs but my groupmate made his from javafx. Is it possible to connect this two? We've tried calling javafxapplication like how jframe to jframe does, but it doesn't work. It gives me this error.

*Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: JavaFXApplication11.setVisible *

It says something about setVisible, but i don't understand it. :( Please help me out. I badly needed this for my project.

This is my Java Swing/GUI code

```
    private void GoToControllingActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    this.dispose();
    JavaFXApplication11 m = new JavaFXApplication11();
    m.setVisible(true);
  }
```

It gives an error on the systemout when I click the JButton for going to the javafxapplication. This code added on the very last part of javafxapplication when I encountered an error Swing with setVisible.

```
        void setVisible(boolean b) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }}
```

Comment: Does these answer your question? [Embedding JavaFX in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51870093/embedding-javafx-in-swing) and [JavaFX integration in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50375151/javafx-integration-in-swing)

Comment: If your partner chose to use JavaFX one would assume they're somewhat familiar with the technology. Shouldn't they be able to tell you how to launch a JavaFX application?

Comment: He doesn't know how to do it either.  He used it because it works efficiently for our project. He just found a source in the internet that does exactly what we need to do and modified it a bit. I thought of making a swing like that javafx but it was harder than i think

Comment: Then I recommend creating a [mre] demonstrating the problem, then add it to your question via an [edit]. Also explain what _specifically_ you actually want to happen (i.e. the desired goal). If you're getting any errors, include them in your question as well. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked my professor, and he gave me the exact answer i needed. I used

```
Application.launch(JavaFXApplication11.class);
this.dispose();
```

And it worked well. :)
Now I need to go back from javafx to swing. And I used

```
Stage stage = (Stage) btn.getScene().getWindow();
stage.close();
Monitoring m = new Monitoring();
m.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked my professor, and he gave me the exact answer i needed. I used

```
Application.launch(JavaFXApplication11.class);
this.dispose();
```

And it worked well. :)
Now I need to go back from javafx to swing. And I used

```
Monitoring m = new Monitoring();
m.setVisible();
this.dispose();
```

Now my new problem is, this.dispose() doesn't work on javafx. Haha

Comment: `Application.launch(JavaFXApplication11.class);
this.dispose();`  disposes `this` only after you close `JavaFXApplication11`. Is that what you wanted ?

Comment: I'd recommend using a [JFXPanel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm) over this approach or just re-write your code in JavaFX so you don't need to deal with two different UI toolkits.